# Copy and paste into forms in Access 2010 and Access 2013 different behavior

Tags: ms-access-2013

Part of my unit uses Access 2010  and the other uses Access 2013. We have forms that we use in the database.

When using the Access 2010 you can either copy and paste into the form or use snipit/snagit then paste. But Access 2013 will not allow you to copy paste but if you do snipit/snagit and paste in an email then copy again from there it will then allow you to paste in the form.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your code? I left my crystal ball in the other pants.

Comment: You can use http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/ to see exactly what is in the Clipboard after copying from Acc2010 / Acc2013 / Email. But since no code is involved, there is probably nothing you can do about it.